# Spawn Rate of bunnies in Bloons Monkey City?

Tags: ios, bloons-monkey-city

In Bloons Monkey City, there is an easter event going on which spawns chocolate egg stealing bunnies in your town. What is the spawn rate of these bunnies?

From my observation, one spawns every 10 minutes and the cap seems to be 6 bunnies at any one time. But I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cap is 10. Usually 8 are on road, 2 off-road. About 4 are hard to find. Sorry I'm late, but the Bloon Spy event is the same.